# Issue: JS error when changing div content

Tags: javascript, html

I have been doing this as normal for all my other websites, but for some reason, this is not working, this is my javascript: `document.getElementById("time").innerText = "test";`
and this is my HTML: `<div id="time"></div>` I don't understand why it's not working because it's worked on all my other projects. This is the error message I get: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of null` Thanks.

Comment: can you tell us when you call this script? Seems like the DOM is not fully rendered when you are trying to call this script

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your script before `</body>` and run it.

Answer (score 0):

You try to get an element which is not rendered yet in DOM. You can put the javascript code just before the `</body>` like @Babar said or wrap your code in

```
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById("time").innerText = "test";
}
```

Hope it helps.